# Getting arbitrary paths to animate by moving the shortest distance in Snap.svg

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I have a canvas. 
In this canvas I have a closed path, and I am trying to morph this path into a different path.

Paths can have any number of points(>=3).

I have two paths:

```
    var path1 = "M50,50L200,50,200,200,50,200z"
    var path2 = "M300,200L50,200,50,50,200,50z"
```

This is what I'm using to animate the morphing:

```
    var path = paper.path(path1).attr({'stroke':'black','fill':'white'})
    var currentPath = 1
    path.click(function () {
        if(currentPath==1) {
            path.stop().animate({d: path2},2000, function () {
                currentPath=2
            })

        }
        else {
            path.stop().animate({d: path1},2000,function () {
                currentPath=1
            })
        }
    })
```

This is the situation I want to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelSel/vgw3qxpg/7/

This is the situation I want to avoid. 
http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelSel/vgw3qxpg/6/

Is there any way to tell snap to do the animation by using the shortest distance to each point?

Note:  I cannot just 'rewrite' the paths in reverse order (which would fix them) because it's the client who positions the points arbitrarily.

What can I do?

I would love to add more details if my question is unclear.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this (other than coding your own complex morphing with checks).

It uses basic interpolation between the points, so its important to get the devs to move the points in their svg creation rather than just creating a new svg from scratch that could have points start from any position.

There is no reason though to my knowledge why you couldn't still rotate the path points with a bit of clever code though, even if the client has positioned them arbitrarily, but I don't think thats simple.

Comment: Rotating is easy. Even reversing is easy. 
The crux is knowing when to do it. It's pretty simple with simple shapes but gets pretty complicated with more complex ones. 
I'm thinking maybe to put a point in the center of the point cloud and create a clock. Then check on what 'hours' the first and last points are found. if the last point is a 'later' hour, I should flip it.

Comment: yes, I was assuming you mean you want something that works 100% of the time. If its not dynamic (eg you never know the file that will be loaded), then I assume its more complex, if you know in advance, I'm not sure I see the problem in rotating a certain number of points, and fixing that in some function call parameter or something.

Comment: yeah.. I tried my solution, its effectiveness is very limited. This is a hard one for me!

Comment: Ian, do you have any idea how one would start writing this complex morphing code? I don't mind putting in a few days of work for this... I just don't know how it works under the hood

Comment: You could take a look at http://jamiepopkin.blogspot.ca/2015/05/morphing-between-svg-shapes.html which does some morphing on arbitrary number of ports, but I suspect it still does basic linear interpolation under the hood.